# Java program compiles fine, yet returning nullPointerException on run?

Tags: java

I've posted my program for review on code review (stackexchange).
Everything worked fine, After I came home I was told to use a IDE.

I opened my source with Eclipse IDE, and then I started getting (both on the IDE, or without) this error upon run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at games.Spin.rand(Spin.java:68)
        at games.Spin.<init>(Spin.java:10)
        at games.GameHandler.<init>(GameHandler.java:8)
        at Mains.startGame(Mains.java:16)
        at Mains.main(Mains.java:9)
```

Why is it doing that? My mate has reviewed my code, and could not find anything wrong with it?.

I am very new to java, tried at attempting going deeper in OO.

My code is located at code review thread (3 classes):

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/28197/improving-my-java-object-oriented-review

What is wrong with it? Why is it giving me that exception?

Line 68: `return r.nextInt(x);`

```
    public int rand(int x) {
        return r.nextInt(x);
    }
```

That's how I create r object:

```
    /**
    * Creating new Random object.
    **/

    private Random r = new Random();
```

Mains.java:

import games.GameHandler;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

```
public class Mains {

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        //Start the game
        startGame();

    }

    private static void startGame() {

        //Declares
        GameHandler handler = new GameHandler();
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);   
        boolean game = true;
        String input = "";  

        //Print program welcome text
        handler.printStart();

        //While in game...
        while (game) {
            //Getting input ready for new commands from the player
            input = console.nextLine();

            //Checking if input was set.
            if (input != null) {
                //Selecting the game you want to play.
                handler.selectGame(input);

                //If game was selected.. then.. let's start playing.
                while (handler.inGame) {
                    //Use will say something.
                    input = console.nextLine();

                    //If it was "exit", it will go back and select another game.
                    if (input.equals("exit")) {
                        handler.exitGame();
                    } else {
                        //Play again.
                        handler.continueGame(input);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GameHandler.java:

package games;
import java.io.*;

```
public class GameHandler {

    private String[] games = {"Spin", "Tof"};
    private String[] navigation = {"Back", "Start"};
    private Spin spin = new Spin();
    private boolean spinGame = false;
    private boolean tofGame = false;
    public boolean inGame = false;

    /**
    * Method printStart
    *
    * Will welcome the player to the program.
    */
    public void printStart() {

        this.print(0, "Welcome to the program!");
        this.print(0, "Please select a game: " + this.availableGames());

    }

    /**
    * Method available games
    *
    * This will print all the games that are located in the games array in one row.
    **/

    private String availableGames() {
        String names = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < games.length; i++) {
            names = (names + games[i]);
            if (i < games.length -1) {
                names = (names + ", ");
            }
        }

        return names;
    }

    /**
    * Method selectGame
    *
    * This will select the given game.
    * @param command The entered command.
    **/

    public void selectGame(String command) {
        if (this.inArray(command))
        {
            if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("spin")) {
                this.startGame("spin");
            } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("tof")) {
                this.startGame("tof");
            }
        } else {
            this.print(0, "Could not find game!");
        }
    }

    /**
    * Method inArray
    *
    * This will check if the entered game name is exisiting in the games array.
    * If yes, will return a boolean true, else false.
    *
    * @param value The entered game name.
    * @return boolean true/false.
    **/

    private boolean inArray(String value) {
        int returning = 0;
        for (String s : games) {
            if (value.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
                returning = 1;
            }
        }
        if (returning == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Method startGame
    *
    * Will start the game, and print instructions.
    * will set the game boolean to true.
    **/

    private void startGame(String game) {
        switch (game) {
            case "spin":
                this.print(0, "Welcome to spin game!");
                this.print(0, "Please click on any key to spin!");
                spinGame = true;
            break;
            case "tof":
            break;
        }

        inGame = true;
    }

    /**
    * Method continueGame
    *
    * Will continue the game, either spin again, or print new question or even answer.
    * @param command The entered command.
    **/
    public void continueGame(String command) {
        while (inGame) {
            if (spinGame) {
                this.spinWheel();
                // Break out of the loop.
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * Method exitGame
    *
    * Exit the game..
    **/

    public void exitGame() {
        spinGame = false;
        tofGame = false;
        this.printStart();
    }

    /**
    * Method spinWheel
    *
    * This will spin the wheel.
    **/

    private void spinWheel() {
        this.print(0, spin.spinWheel());
    }

    /**
    * Method print
    *
    * Prints text using System.out
    * @param type printing type (Println/print).
    * @param message The message
    **/

    private void print(int type, String message) {
        switch (type) {
            case 0:
                System.out.println(message);
            break;
            case 1:
                System.out.print(message);
            break;              
        }
    }
}
```

Spin.java:

package games;
import java.util.Random;

```
public class Spin {

    /**
    * The base auth we are going to work with..
    **/

    private int auth = this.rand(1000) / 5; 

    /**
    * Creating new Random object.
    **/

    private Random r = new Random();

    /**
    * Method spinWheel
    *
    * Spins the damn wheel..
    * @return spinned value + if you won or not.
    **/

    public String spinWheel() {
        return this.spinWheel(this.rand(100));
    }

    /**
    * spinWheel
    *
    * Returning results.
    **/

    private String spinWheel(int number) {

        int result = this.Calculate(this.rand(number));

        if (result < 101) {
            return "You have won the game!" + result;
        } else {
            return "You've lost the game!" + result;
        }
    }

    /**
    * Method calculate
    *
    * Calculates the spin.
    * @return the spinned number.
    **/


    private int Calculate(int Number) {

        int var = this.rand(101);

        int holder = (var * Number) / 2;

        return holder + this.auth;
    }

    /**
    * Shortcut for nextInt of Random
    **/

    public int rand(int x) {
        return r.nextInt(x);
    }

}
```

Comment: We're going to need to see more code than this. Can you trim your program down to a complete, compilable version that demonstrates the error and post that?

Comment: NPE is a so called Runtime Exception, meaning that it occurs at runtime (commenting on your title). There are no objects when compiling. First of all, check what's null and try to backtrace it by reading your code. If that doesn't work, step through it at runtime using a debugger.

Comment: I have looked at it, it doesn't look like any of the objects are null there. as I am declaring it at the top of the class. I've posted the code on there though, these are all of my classes.

Comment: Next time, open a debugger, set a breakpoint on the offending line, and backtrace from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rand` is invoked before the `Random` instance `r` is initialised. Switch the order or these 2 statements

```
private int auth = this.rand(1000) / 5; 
private Random r = new Random();
```

should be

```
private Random r = new Random();
private int auth = this.rand(1000) / 5;
```

Comment: Better idea: use a constructor, to make initialization order more explicit.

Answer (score 2):

Make the assignment of r the first thing in your Spinwheel class definition, i.e. put it before it is used in this.rand(1000):

```
public class Spin {
  /**
   * Creating new Random object.
   **/
  private Random r = new Random();

  /**
   * The base auth we are going to work with..
   **/
  private int auth = this.rand(1000) / 5;
```

Comment: I put it above the code where it uses the method rand(), I did not know that it could occur because that, it now works fine. Why didn't my compiler let me know about this error?

Comment: @JonyKale: The compiler didn't realize the problem. In general, it's not possible to detect all errors at compile time. If we could, programs wouldn't have bugs in them.

Answer (score 1):

`r` is null, so you can't call any instance method on `r`. Make sure you intialize `r` before using it.

More specifically, in this line:

```
private int auth = this.rand(1000) / 5;
```

you're calling the `rand()` method before r has been initialized (it's initialized right after).

Comment: Not sure why I got downvoted. My answer has always been correct, and has been as complete as it could be given the amount of information provided in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the line causing the `NullPointerException`:

```
private int auth = this.rand(1000) / 5;
```

Since this line comes *before* the initialization for `r`, you are invoking `rand` *before* `r` was initialized. In that case `r` is `null` in `rand` and that's your exception.

This is obvious from your stack trace:

```
at games.Spin.rand(Spin.java:68)
at games.Spin.<init>(Spin.java:10)
```

Note that the exception is happening in the *initializer*. From there, it's easy to back out what is going on.

You need to initialize `r` first, that is, move the initialization line for `r` before the initialization line for `auth`. Thus:

```
private Random r = new Random();
private int auth = this.rand(1000) / 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `r` is being used before it is instantiated within statement `private int auth = this.rand(1000) / 5;` . So , JVM is seeing `r` as `null` , which is leading to `NPE`. To get rid of this problem within `Spin` class declare the fields as follows:

```
    private Random r = new Random();
    private int auth = this.rand(1000) / 5;
```